# Overriding __init__ in threading.Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, oop, inheritance

Examining this undocumented `threading.Thread` subclass and need a little guidance.

My understanding of what the class does is:

```
"""Reload module if it's been updated since last compiled."""
```

The code:

```
class Hotswap(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, out, mod, gen='generate', *args, **kwargs):
        self.out = out # this is an output destination
        self.mod = mod
        self.genname = gen # this is a generator from the "mod"
        self.gen = getattr(mod, self.genname)(*args, **kwargs)
        self.loaded = self.current_modtime
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True

    @property
    def current_modtime(self):
        return os.path.getmtime(self.mod.__file__.replace("pyc", "py"))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.current_modtime != self.loaded:
                log.info("Hot-swapping module: %s", self.mod.__name__)
                self.mod = reload(self.mod)
                self.loaded = self.current_modtime
                self.gen = getattr(self.mod, self.genname)(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            self.handle(self.gen.next())

    def handle(self, elem):
        self.out(elem)
```

This is an example of call to the class:

```
Hotswap(InfoHandler.add, info, 'generate', info_queue, first_frame).start()
```

Where InfoHandler creates a TornadIO socket, `info` is a module, `generate` it's method and `info_queue, first_frame` are *args.

What I don't understand is how `out, mod, gen='generate'` tie in with `threading.Thread`'s `group=None, target=None, name=None`. Do group, target and name just get initialized as their defaults (none) when `threading.Thread.__init__(self)` runs?

Comment: Those are optional so yes, they get set to whatever their default values are which happen to be `None`. The call to `threading.Thread.__init__(self)` is just calling the superclass' `__init__` same thing as using `super(Hotswap, self).__init__()`

Comment: The `super` call would be within the __init__, right? And `Hotswap.__dict__` will return all of the attributes from `Hotswap` and `threading.Thread`?

Comment: @Ngenator - does this question warrant even being posted? Wondering if I should delete. Does it actually invite a real answer?

Comment: I'll answer with more info. Yes the super call could just replace `threading.Thread.__init__(self)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `threading.Thread`, you will see

```
threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={})
```

So yes, those values will get set to `None` when the superclass' `__init__` is called.

The `__dict__` question is a bit more complicated. Take the following code (I used the same names as your question for clarity):

```
class Thread(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.a = a

    def b(self):
        pass

class Hotswap(Thread):
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        print("Before init: {}".format(self.__dict__))

        self.x = x

        super(Hotswap, self).__init__()

        print("After init: {}".format(self.__dict__))

    def y(self):
        pass

print("On Hotswap class: {}".format(Hotswap.__dict__))
h = Hotswap()
print("On Hotswap instance: {}".format(h.__dict__))
```

The output would be something like this:

```
On Hotswap class: {'y': <function y at 0x24b9bc>, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x24b97c>}
Before init: {}
After init: {'a': None, 'x': None}
On Hotswap instance: {'a': None, 'x': None}
```

As you can see, it doesn't take into account the superclass (or it's own) attributes unless you call it on an instance.

Comment: So  `class.__dict__` contains functions and special objects, but the `instance.__dict__` only contains attributes?

Comment: was getting error in the print statements so submitted an edit using `.format()`.

Comment: Check out this https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy at the bottom of the classes and class instances sections.

Comment: Sorry about the error, wrote it for 2.7. But the `__dict__` contents/usage is different depending on the `type` it is used with.